# C++'s pure virtual function implementation and header files

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract, pure-virtual

I'm having some trouble implementing pure virtual functions inherited from some abstract class, when the classes in question are divided into `*.h` and `*.cpp` files. The compiler (`g++`) tells me that the derived class cannot be instantiated because of the existence of pure functions.

```
/** interface.h**/
namespace ns
{
    class Interface {
        public:
            virtual void method()=0;
    }
}

/** interface.cpp**/
namespace ns
{
    //Interface::method()() //not implemented here
}

/** derived.h **/
namespace ns
{
    class Derived : public Interface {
        //note - see below
    }
}

/** derived.cpp **/
namespace ns
{
    void Derived::Interface::method() { /*doSomething*/ }
}

/** main.cpp **/
using namespace ns;
int main()
{
    Interface* instance = new Derived; //compiler error
}
```

Does this mean that I have to **declare** the method() twice - in the Interface's `*.h` and in the `derived.h` too? Is there no other way around?

Comment: First, there's no reason to have a .cpp file in which the only thing is a blank namespace. You don't need an implementation file for a header congaing an abstract class.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You forgot to declare `Derived::method()`.

You tried to define it at least, but wrote `Derived::Interface::method()` rather than `Derived::method()`, but you did not even attempt to declare it. Therefore it doesn't exist.

Therefore, `Derived` has no `method()`, therefore the pure virtual function `method()` from `Interface` was not overridden... and therefore, `Derived` is also pure virtual and cannot be instantiated.

Also, `public void method()=0;` is not valid C++; it looks more like Java. Pure virtual member functions have to actually be virtual, but you did not write `virtual`. And access specifiers are followed by a colon:

```
public:
    virtual void method() = 0;
```

Comment: The void bit probably a typo, it's not java either.

Comment: @time4tea: Indeed it's not valid Java either, but with the missing colon and the implication that the access specifier has been seen as something joined to the declaration, it's a damn sight closer than it is to C++!

Comment: The syntax was my typo, see my comment to the opening post :) sorry about that.  
Also, the `Derived::Interface::method()` is my attempt to define a function that should be inherited from Interface.
My original question was something along the lines "can I implement (define) an inherited pure virtual function without explicitly declaring it in the derived class's `.h` file?". The reason I'd like to do that is to avoid cluttering my header file when the class inherits from several interfaces, containing several pure virtuals each...

Comment: @Neo: And the answer is no. :)

Comment: @Thomalak Geret'kal: Ah. Pity. :( Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 18):

You have to declare your method in the subclass.

```
// interface.hpp
class Interface {
public:
    virtual void method()=0;
}

// derived.hpp
class Derived : public Interface {
public:
    void method() override;
}

// derived.cpp
void
Derived::method()
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I think you mean **declare** (not define).

Comment: @MikeSlutsky yes I did.

Comment: @robert Thank you for the answer. Can you ellaborate on the reasons for that ? Coming from Java it seems very dirty to have to do that. When we have many derived different classes and many methods in the base interface we need to change a lot of files in case of change in the base interface.

Comment: @ManuelSelva you can't define a method in a class unless it's declared in that class. This is independent of whether this class derives from anything.

Answer (score 0):

You also did not call constructor properly - it's also a method;

```
 Interface* instance = new Derived;
```

Should be

```
 Interface* instance = new Derived();
```

Comment: This is C++ and you certainly can create objects with both `new Derived;` and `new Derived();`. There's a certain difference between the two (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new) ), but in this case they're equivalent because there are no fields to initialize.